# Blog Settings import/export in Wordpress Network environment

Tags: multisite, options, export

I can't use PHPMyAdmin to export/import my blogs from one server to an other because I'm using Wordpress Network.

Export/import works pretty well for Posts, custom posts types and their media, but not for the Blog settings themselves

How could I export my blog settings?

Some examples:

- sizes for Thumbnails, medium, large images
- Pictures cropping
- Date format
- show excerpts
- how many articles per pages
- ...

my main goal being to apply all my beta website settings to the main website when fully tested and approved.

Comment: why cant you export that from the database?

Comment: maybe I could export wp_63_options (if my blog is the 63rd one) and identify which lines are for the settings. Maybe it will end with a homemade plugin to select only the right options if nothing exists

Comment: What do you mean by "one server to another"? And I mean: is it going to be a transfer from **Multisite** to Multisite? Or to Single site? *At first*, it doesn't really matters if it's the same or another server...

Comment: from a multisite (beta) to an other multisite. On 2 different LAMP.

Comment: Sorry, but, in a second reading, I think this needs clarification as well: how does it comes you "***can't use PHpMyAdmin***"¿?

Comment: exporting `wp_31_options` from the beta server, importing in `wp_14_options` to the main server, excluding all the `siteurl` `home` `upload_path` `fileupload_url` and others that I didn't see yet. It seemed to me all but the best way to deal safely with a website working that I need to update with my latest theme version.

Comment: I mean: the target website is already running with visitors

Answer (score 1):

Export the options table that is specific to the multisite blog in question (just the option names and values), import them into the new options table on the new site.

This will work for every option that doesn't use a prefixed option name, which is only user-specific stuff like capabilities and roles.

Comment: if there's such a table, it's exactly what I'm looking for. But I need you to be a bit more precise because I can see only get_option($name). Do you mean that I should create my own plugin to do get_option() and set_option() ?

Comment: I thought you were looking directly at the database.

In a multisite install, each site gets its own set of tables. So there will be wp_3_options and wp_4_options and so on. These options are those that are specific to that particular site. Just export all of them, minus the ID's, and put them in the new site's options table. You'd use phpMyAdmin or similar to do this.

Comment: sorry, now I understand. I also should exclude `siteurl` `home` `upload_path` `fileupload_url`. I only need data from the submenus **settings** available in `/wp-admin/`, it's weird that there's no way to separate them... all the `/wp-admin/options-*.php`

Comment: On a multisite setup, things like those generally don't matter so much. The multisite code handles them, and it has its own sitewide options table.

Comment: It doesn't seem to me the safest way to deal with a website working that I need to update with my latest theme version without accidental interruption. **'generally don't matter** you said... I will try your solution today, but it seems a good way to get side effects one day without noticing in time

Comment: Confirmed, it's a big mess, there's way too much data that shouldn't be changed. Maybe if I had knew that I wanted to use this method my all system would be different so that I can simply import/export the whole table. I'll consider it, but I will more likely create a plug in to select which data I really nead. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking about this last night and don't want to 'self promote' too much here

If you can't access PHPMyAdmin, my database backup plugin [dbc backup 2](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/dbc-backup-2/) will create the SQL export for you of all tables in your WordPress install.

You can then open the export in a SQL editor like SQLYog and you'll be able to see all the tables in your database.

But from experience you don't save time editing in SQL, many of the things you are looking for like setting post per page, and excerpt length are quicker to change from within WP-Admin then reading through all the rows in the WP_options table.

Remember you can always go to `/wp-admin/options.php` to see all the options for that site.

Take care - some options in the database have a checkvalue (length) as well
example username admin may have a value of (5) next to it.

Comment: thank you, I fully agree with you. When I need the create a copy for Beta tests I will more likely be happy to know your plugin.